# Coroutine issue in script for Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a script `WebSourceConfig` to read the JSON config file, and use `WebSourceLink` script to render buttons into Unity app. `WebSourceLink` always need to run after `WebSourceConfig` finished, otherwise, there will no any data to parse in the app.

I'm using coroutine, and IEnumerator method to ask running in this sequence.

```
public class WebSourceLink : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WebSourceConfig configSource;

    //Buttons references
    public Button buttonPrefab;
    public GameObject Buttons;

    //Browser windows references
    public GameObject browserWindow;
    public GameObject Windows;

    private Vector2 _nextWindowPosition = new(-900f, 0f);

    void Start()
    {
        // Start coroutne to wait for read config file
        StartCoroutine(WaitForConfigRead());
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForConfigRead()
    {
        // Continually check if the config file has been read
        while (configSource.webConfig == null)
        {
            // Use the yield return statement to pause the coroutine
            // until the next frame
            Debug.Log("Null data parsed");
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log(configSource.webConfig);

        // Once the file is read by WebSourceConfig, read the config data
        ReadData();

        InvokeRepeating("ReadData", 300, 5 * 60);
    }

......

}
```

But the `configSource == null` or `configSource.webConfig == null` always be `false`, `configSource`'s value is `Main Camera (WebSourceConfig)`, `configSource.webConfig`'s value is `WebConfiguration` no matter the config file be downloaded or not.

What's wrong with my script? How to can I fix it?

Here is my `WebSourceConfig` script to read downloaded file. I also use coroutine, it works to read config file only if the file is downloaded.

```
public class WebSourceConfig : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WebConfiguration webConfig;

    // Store the last time the config file was read
    private DateTime lastReadTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    void Start()
    {
        // Start the coroutine to wait for the file to be downloaded
        StartCoroutine(WaitForConfigFile());
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForConfigFile()
    {
        // Continually check if the config file has been downloaded yet
        while (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "config.json")))
        {
            // Use the yield return statement to pause the coroutine
            // until the next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        // Once the file is downloaded, read the config file
        ReadConfigFile();

        // Call the CheckConfigFile method every 5 minutes
        InvokeRepeating("CheckConfigFile", 300, 5 * 60);
    }

    void CheckConfigFile()
    {
        // Check for changes to the config file
        // If the file has changed, read it again
        if (HasConfigFileChanged())
        {
            ReadConfigFile();
        }
    }

    void ReadConfigFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // Use the Path.Combine method to create the full path to the JSON file
            string jsonPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "config.json");

            // Read the JSON file into a string
            string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);

            // Convert the JSON string into a strongly-typed object
            webConfig = JsonUtility.FromJson<WebConfiguration>(json);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // Print the error message to the console
            Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    bool HasConfigFileChanged()
    {
        // Get the last modified time of the file
        string jsonPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "config.json");
        var lastModifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(jsonPath);

        // Check if the last modified time is different from the time when we last read the file
        if (lastModifiedTime != lastReadTime)
        {
            // Update the lastReadTime to the current time
            lastReadTime = lastModifiedTime;

            // Return true to indicate that the file has changed
            return true;
        }

        // Return false if the file has not changed
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the `WebSourceConfig` script and how it is used we could only guess. Polling is usually the worst way to handle something like this. Why not have the code that reads the config call this script directly? You could also just add a `bool` to `WebSourceConfig` to indicate that the config has been read.

Comment: Impossible to determine the issue. From your code, there's no indication that `WebSourceConfig` has ever been issued a command to read any source data. And there's no indication that `WebSourceConfig` (or some other process) would update `WebSourceLink.configSource` when done. The code shown never updates `WebSourceLink.configSource` which would always remain null.

Comment: I'm not too sure if monitoring a config file for changes during gameplay is a good idea, particularly in the UI thread even if it is once every 5 minutes.  Remember you are making a game **not** say an ASP.NET website so I can't imagine a use case for this.  Config, heavy assets should be loaded at level start and not during.  https://www.amazon.com/Engine-Architecture-Third-Jason-Gregory/dp/1138035459

Comment: general hint right away: `Application.streamingAssetsPath` will be read-only in a build so you can't use that later .. you would probably rather go for `Application.persistentDataPath`

Comment: and agree with @Deleted ... why not combine both into one single script and parse the config once as soon as the download finishes? In general have in mind that FileIO is always a bottle neck ... why not rather use some proper events instead of `File.Exists` if you already know that the file can not exist until you downloaded it?